# Bind scope to function outside of function call

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop

An example:

```
var MyClass = (function () {
    function MyClass() {
        // construct
    }

    MyClass.prototype.clickEvent = function() {
        this.doSomething();
    };

    MyClass.prototype.doSomething = function() {
        // do something here
    };

    return MyClass;
})();

var mc = new MyClass();
$('my-ele').click(mc.clickEvent.bind(mc));
```

I need to bind mc to mc.clickEvent to make this work. Is there another way to do this? It works fine, it's just it would be nice if there was a way to define the scope of my clickEvent() function without needing to attach .bind(mc) when setting the click event function.

I saw something like this:

```
MyClass.prototype.clickEvent = function() {
    this.doSomething();
}.bind(this);
```

but that didn't work.

Comment: @YauheniLeichanok I'm storing state with properties. It would work without the wrapper, but I need it.

Comment: If the question is only tangentially related to jquery, shouldn't the tag be removed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var MyClass = (function () {
    function MyClass() {
      this.clickEvent = this.clickEvent.bind(this);
    }

    MyClass.prototype.clickEvent = function() {
      this.doSomething();
    };

    MyClass.prototype.doSomething = function() {
        alert('something');
    };

    return MyClass;
})();

var mc = new MyClass();
$('.my-ele').click(mc.clickEvent);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<a href=#" class="my-ele">test</a>
```

Do this for binding all its class methods.

```
function MyClass() {
    for (var i in this) {
        if (typeof this[i] === 'function') {
          this[i] = this[i].bind(this);   
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @user11406 Please be aware that by doing this you effectively "lock in" the method and future changes to the prototype will not be visible to previously constructed instances.

Answer (score 0):

If you were using `mc.clickEvent` directly it would work as you expect.  `click` is actually changing the binding and by explicitly calling `bind` like that you are telling it not too.

You also might be able to mimic that from the start.  (That's what [Moogs answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30009173/142161) does.

An easier way that might come close would be to wrap the call like this:

```
$('my-ele').click(function(i,e) { mc.clickEvent(i,e); })
```

This way within `clickEvent` `this` will still be `mc`.

Answer (score 0):

Your last snippet doesn't work because you didn't wrap the function before calling the `bind` method like so:

```
function MyClass() {
    this.clickEvent = (function() {
        this.doSomething();
    }).bind(this);
}
```

However, **this is inefficient** because it requires the function to be defined inside the constructor which *does not take advantage of the prototype chain*. I just felt it would be helpful explaining why your last snippet didn't work.